# How to let hibernate create a complex unique constraint?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using `hibernate` to autogenerate my tables.
Now I want to add a rather complex unique constraint as follows:

`UNIQUE KEY person_unique ((coalesce(firstname, 'null')), (coalesce(lastname, 'null')), (coalesce(dob, 'null')));`

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   @Id long id;

   @Column(nullable=true)
   String firstname, lastname;

   @Column(nullable=true)
   LocalDate dob;
}
```

I want to use the constraint to prevent inserting duplicate entries also respecting null value fields.

But how can I tell hibernate to create those unique key?

Because a `@Table` annotation does not accept a native sql statement. The following is **not** sufficient:

```
@Table(name = "person",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "unique_person",
        columnNames = {"firstname", "lastname", "dob"}) }
)
```

Question: how can I get the `coalesce()` there inside?

Comment: I don't think there is any solution using Hibernate's DDL generator. You could create a separate script to have it applied via Spring. Spring boot will auto-apply a file named schema.sql (will that execute after Hibernate's DDL is complete?), otherwise you could have a bean do similar via @PostConstruct method.

Comment: But then I'd have to problem how I could alter the existing (by hibernate ddl generated) table to add a constraint, and only if it does not exist yet? Afaik there is no ADD UNIQUE KEY **IF NOT EXISTS**...

Comment: There will be a way to check you'd just need to find what it is for your database and use some conditional logic.

Comment: You should better use Flyway or Liquibase for database migration instead of hibernate ddl.

Comment: Well I don't want to migrate a database. I simply want a setup that either creates it from scratch if not exists, or validates it against the (hibernate) definitions.

Comment: So what is wrong with this? `@Table(name = "person", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "unique_person", columnNames = {"coalesce(firstname, 'null')", "coalesce(lastname, 'null')", "coalesce(dob, 'null')"}) } )`

Comment: If that doesn't work, you should be able to do something similar by creating a unique index which is also possible on the `@Table` annotation.